# CSV displayed Arabic letter as?

Tags: csv

I had a csv file initially it has Arabic letters in it, I did not know and I have made changes to it like putting formulas and saved it. Later when I open it I found all arabic characters are displayed as ?.

I browsed internet and tried all ways of importing data from this csv but the arabic characters that were saved as ? are still appearing as ?. I badly want to retrieve them as those were my leads.

Is there any way that I can extract Arabic characters from that file which was saved already. or is there any way I can restore the earliest version which has Arabic text in it. I do not have history version in windows so that option is not available.

Realy any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate between file content, and display of the file.

The **file** actually does not contain "arabic" but a series of bytes. How these are displayed is totally up to the program that read the file. Simplified it's kind of like the string `1234` which you can read as either "12" and "34" or "1234".

The **display** is an interpretation of the file content.  So it's not directly possible to say if it's wrong or not.

The offending program MAY have written the data back in an incorrect way, either directly as "?" characters, or as meaningless data. Then the file data is changed forever, and can't be brought back in that file.

If the offending program writes the data right, but always displays "?", the data may be there - you need to check in a unicode-enabled program.

Make a simple test with a sample dummy file. See [this sample file](https://file.io/QkclZZPoocnZ)

Comment: initially the content has proper Arabic text it was a lead file with names, email and other data. I mistakenly open it in Ms Excel added some forumulas and save it. Later I found that all arabic name or content turned into ?. now with no way I can get back that arabic text.